# Export to excel with russian file name

Tags: firefox, browser, utf-8, struts2, inputstream

I have an excel file that Im attempting to download using struts2 framework.

I have my excel file (InputStream object) on the value stack and here's my configuraiton in struts.xml:

```
  <result name="ExcelExport" type="stream">
    <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=${reportFileName}.xls</param>
    <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
    <param name="inputName">xlsStream</param>
    <param name="bufferSize">3000</param>
  </result>
```

The reportFileName parameter is also on the value stack and it's i18n-based. Using google chrome, and when the language is Russian, the downloaded excel looks good i.e. both the downloaded file name and the excel content display russian characters.

Using Firefox, the downloaded excel has valid Russian content but the file name is gibberish e.g. '%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B.xls'

Does anyone have an idea how this issue can be resolved?

Comment: issue seems more of browser specific rather than S2 issue.I saw this thread on Mozilla forum, have a look at it http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2157533

Comment: I heard that people have not been able to do that in Firefox. So, better to substitute with A-Z letters.